# Which UIWebView caused the keyboard to appear?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, uikeyboard

In iOS, if you have multiple UIWebViews in your View with html form input content in each and the user clicks a text input inside of one of the UIWebViews, how can you find out which UIWebView they initiated the action from which caused the keyboard to appear?

I need to know which UIWebView triggered the keyboard to fix the scrolling inside the html window. My UIWebViews are created dynamically and i don't always know how many will be there and sending a call to all of my UIWebViews will mess up the user's location on one of the pages.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[center addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `object` property of the `NSNotification` object passed in as the argument of the observer method? Or isn't it the `UIWebView` that is the sender of the notification?

Comment: sadly the UIWebView doesn't send the notification so i can't track it that way.